# An element of $L^2(0,T;V_n)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $V$ be Hilbert with basis $w_j.$ Let $V_n = \text{span}(w_1, ..., w_n)$. Is it true that every element $v \in L^2(0,T;V_n)$ can be written as
$$v(t) = \sum_{j=1}^n a(t)w_j?$$
I think so. But my doubt comes because I am told that $L^2(0,T;V_n)$ has basis
$$\{l_iw_j : i \in \mathbb{N}, j = 1,...,n\}$$
where $l_i$ is the basis for $L^2(0,T)$, so this contradicts what I wrote above...

Comment: there is no contradiction here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\{l_i(t)\cdot w_j : i \in \mathbb{N}, j = 1,...,n\}$ is a basis you can write
$$
v(t)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \alpha_{ij} l_i(t) w_j 
$$
After changing order of summation we get
$$
v(t)
=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_{ij} l_i(t) w_j 
=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n w_j \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_{ij} l_i(t) 
$$
It is remains to put 
$$
a_j(t)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_{ij} l_i(t) 
$$